# Can Clonezilla make SSD image with deleted files?

Tags: clonezilla

I just deleted a very important file on an NTFS formatted SSD and need to recover it. Before starting recovery, I would like to make a disk image with all data on the disk, just in case I make situation worse than it already is.

Would Clonezilla work on deleted files on an SSD? The SSD has TRIM support.

Comment: +1 I don't know enough about how Clonezilla does it (you are looking for something that does a sector-by-sector copy...Ghost 2003 with the -ia and fro switches could do it if you don't find your answer about Clonezilla), but I seriously commend you for cloning your disk before doing anything to it, or the copy, that could recover files, because you are right, you could make the situation worse. If more people did that, we would have a few less serious disk recovery questions.